# Button fling animating background

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `OnTouchListener` which uses [onFling()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to determine when user is flinging/swiping the view. now I would like to animate the background of the view according to current `x` position of `onTouch()`, how can I accomplish this?

Exmaple gif: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a rect which would act as the swiping color. Now all you have to do is update everytime the touch position changes.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mRect.right = (int) event.getX();

            invalidate();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Remember to initialize the Rect with correct height.